# Understanding computation of voltage

Tags: voltage

I am trying to find the voltage near the resistance with 4 Ohms. Now I took an easy example so that I can understand well. I think I can do it using Kirchhoff laws to find the currents then apply a current divider in order to find the current near the 4 Ohm resistance. Is there an easier or more direct way? Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Can you show more of your work? How were you going to use Kirchhoff's Laws to find currents in the circuit? This looks like homework, and we expect a little more effort before we offer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use KVL to solve this, you'll be done...the result will include the voltage you need without any need to apply the current divider rule.

If you just want to solve the problem, notice that the voltage across the 4-ohm resistor is exactly the same as the voltage across the 2-ohm resistor. So if you take the equivalent resistance by combining these parallel resistors, and solve for the voltage across that equivalent resistor, you'll have the voltage you want.